# Не выходит решить задачу

Tags: python

В магазине для упаковки подарков есть N кубических коробок красного, зелёного и синего цвета. Самой интересной считается упаковка подарка по принципу матрёшки  — подарок упаковывается в одну из коробок, та в свою очередь в другую коробку и т. д., при этом цвета коробок отличаются. Одну коробку можно поместить в другую, если длина её стороны хотя бы на 7 единицы меньше длины стороны другой коробки.

Определите наибольшее количество коробок, которое можно использовать для упаковки одного подарка, и максимально возможную длину стороны самой маленькой коробки, где будет находиться подарок. Размер подарка позволяет поместить его в самую маленькую коробку.

Ссылка на файл через файлообменник: https://dropmefiles.com/E7lxG

Вот версия моего кода. Мне нужно посчитать только самое большое количество использованных коробок за раз, но ответ выходит не верный. Правильный 628

```
f = open('26_5988.txt')
k = []
maxlength = 0

for x in f:
    a, b = x.split()
    k.append([int(a), b])

k.sort(reverse=True) #сортирую коробки с самой большой

for j in range(len(k)): #прохожусь по каждой коробке и ищу максимальное кол-во коробок, которое может в неё поместиться.
    podarok = [k[j]]

    for i in range(j + 1, len(k)):

        if podarok[-1][0] - k[i][0] >= 7 and k[i][1] != podarok[-1][1]:
            podarok.append(k[i]) #подарок - коробки, из которых собирается подарок. Отнимаю из самой последней коробки следующую за ней коробку из списка и смотрю, чтобы разница была равна 7 или больше 7, а так же, чтобы цвета отличались. Если это так, то добавляю коробку в подарок.

        maxlength = max(maxlength, len(podarok)) #ищу максимальное кол-во коробок среди подарков.

print(maxlength)
```

Помогите мне исправить мой код, но не пишите полностью новый. Я хочу понять свою ошибку. Спасибо!

Comment: что находится в файле? в каком виде представлены данные? Как искать ошибку, если непонятно, что делает код.

Comment: @Эникейщик Прикрепил файл через файлообменник.

Comment: никто не будет тут скачивать файл через файлообменник. вся необходимая информация должна быть в вопросе

Comment: @Эникейщик Думаю, если бы было возможным, то я бы с радостью вставил текст, содержащий 20000 символов, из файла в вопрос, чтобы вы вручную скопировали эти 20000 символов, но, мне кажется, скачать файл было бы проще и быстрее.

Comment: если бы вы прочитали [ask], то вам бы не казалось.

Comment: @VALON ну вот вам тестовый пример попроще. `[(15, 'B'), (8, 'R'), (8, 'G'), (1, 'R')]`. Ответ должен быть 3 (1:R в 8:G в 15:B), у вас ответ 2.